# Show parameters stored in stack with __fastcall in IDA

Tags: ida, disassembly, decompilation, calling-conventions

This is an extension of my [previous question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18570/23069). Here is a sample of assembly in x64 Windows executable using COM virtual function with [`__fastcall` convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx).

```
mov     [rsp+32], rdx                       ; 5th param
lea     r9, var                             ; 4th param
xor     r8d, r8d                            ; 3rd param
mov     rdx, r14                            ; 2nd param
mov     rcx, r15                            ; 1st param
mov     rax, [rax+24]                       ; 4th function pointer
call    cs:__guard_dispatch_icall_fptr      ; call dynamic dispatch
```

In pseudocode, IDA shows only 4 parameters, 5th one is vanished.

IDA shows like this: `(ppv + 24)(a, b, c, d);`

But the real function definition will be like this: `(ppv + 24)(a, b, c, d, e);`

- What I tried: 1. Add a header file with the correct function definition and with correct position in vtable using Ctrl+F9 key combo, 2. Change compiler calling convention to `__fastcall` in Options > Compiler menu, 3. Change function definition with <kbd>Y</kbd> key.
- Question: How can I allow to show all the stack parameters in a function using IDA (or any extensions)?

Comment: What is, to your understanding, the fifth parameter?

Comment: @NirIzr Oh, I forgot this question. I'll add answer tomorrow. I solved this many days ago.